# How to display the default image if there is no attachment image

Tags: apex, visualforce, images, rendered

This is the default image code:

```
<img class="logo" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.headerLogo)}"/>
```

This is the attachment image:

```
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,PostAttachments[0].Attachments[0].Id)}" width="300px" height="200px"></apex:image>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the rendered attribute may help in this case. I have wrapped your img tag in an outputPanel so there is a processed item to attach a rendered attribute to.  Use the size attribute of a list to get the 'size' - notice there are no parenthesis when using size.

This is just hacked in so you may need to fiddle a bit.

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered= "{!OR(PostAttachments.size=0, PostAttachments[0].Attachments.size = 0)}">
<img class="logo" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.headerLogo)}"/>
</apex:outputPanel>


<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,PostAttachments[0].Attachments[0].Id)}" rendered="{!AND(PostAttachments.size>0, PostAttachments[0].Attachments.size > 0)}"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir.. its working.. got problem with the PostAttachments.size

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onError` event for the image to reassign src of the image:

`<img src = "{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,PostAttachments[0].Attachments[0].Id)}" width="300px" height="200px" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='{!URLFOR($Resource.headerLogo)}';"></img>`

Refer the [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images) for reference